# Hwo to generate code from a Simulink model in Python > 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, simulink

I'm trying to generate c code from different Simulink models by calling Matlab engine in Python.
I see that for calling Matlab you use:

```
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab('-nodesktop')
```

and for running the simulation you do :

```
eng.sim('model')
```

How do I then generate code from the model? Matlab version 2017b. Python version 3.6

Comment: This enables you to run Simulink code in Python (at least, that's what you claim). Why do you want to generate C-code, from Simulink, through MATLAB and then through Python? Why don't you generate the C-code from Simulink directly and skip all the intermediate steps?

Comment: Good point. @Adriaan . That is ofcourse possible but it is not the goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was here:

```
matlabEngine = matlab.engine.start_matlab('-nodesktop')

# Generate code
matlabEngine.rtwbuild(Model)
```

The key I was looking fore was `matlabEngine.rtwbuild(Model)`. and it did indeed generate the code.